# Show that ∇· (∇ x F) = 0 for any vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product

To solve this question, how do I define any vector field $F$, in order to solve it?  I called $F = (ax,by,cz)$, in which case already $\nabla\times F = 0$.
How would i go about proving this?
Many thanks!

Comment: The most brutally simple approach: Write out the curl of a generic $\vec{F}=(F_x,F_y,F_z)$, and then take its divergence. The only assumption required is that all partial derivatives commute, e.g. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_z=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_z.$$

Comment: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath103/kmath103_files/image007.gif

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you define $F$ in terms of smooth functions in each coordinate.  For instance I would write $F = (F_x, F_y, F_z) = F_x\hat{i} + F_y \hat{j} + F_z \hat{k}$ and compute each quantity one at a time.  First you'll compute the curl:

$$
\nabla \times F \;\; =\;\; \left | \begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
F_x & F_y & F_z \\
\end{array} \right | \;\; =\;\; G_x\hat{i} + G_y \hat{j} + G_z\hat{k}
$$

where the functions $G_x, G_y, G_z$ are obtained by computing the determinant.  Then you will want to compute

$$
\nabla\cdot (\nabla\times F) \;\; =\;\; \frac{\partial G_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial G_z}{\partial z}.
$$

You should find that the last equation yields zero.